# How to write a Replace Rule that will Iconize all Rules in a List whose rhs are long String-s?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, output-formatting, string-manipulation, transformation

First, let me illustrate what I'm trying to do. `FormatOptions` is a programming utility that will `Echo` a given `Symbol`-'s `Options` in a `Column` or a multicolumn `Grid` table (to be added later as an Option) so that they are `Sort`-ed (also to be added later) in some particular fashion. The goal is creating a tool that doesn't just spit out a raw list that is difficult to read. The only problem with it is that long `Rule`-s can misshapen the output. Therefore, it would be expedient to automate the `Iconize` step with a `ReplaceAll` (or one like it) `Rule`.

The code below works. As you can see I have one long string pre-Iconized. This works, but I would like to create an expression that will test every RHS `Rule` for example, `StringLength[expr] >= 35`, and `Iconize` them.

```
(* This works, but it's not automated *)

ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll[FormatOptions, stage, rules];

Options[FormatOptions] = {"rawlist" -> True, "iconize" -> True};
FormatOptions[sym_Symbol, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
    nam = 
     Style[("Options[" <> (ToString[Evaluate[sym]]) <> "]"), Bold],
    rul = Evaluate[Options[sym]],
    lab, raw, ops
    },
   lab := 
    "raw list: " <> (ToString[Evaluate[Length[rul]]]) <> " " <> 
     "items";
   raw := If[OptionValue["iconize"], Iconize[rul, lab], rul];
   ops = If[OptionValue["rawlist"], AppendTo[rul, Evaluate[raw]], rul];
   Echo[Row[{nam, Style[" \[Rule] ", Orange], "{   ", Column[ops], 
      "  }"}]]
   ];


Options[stage] = {"backuprate" -> 2, 
   "source" -> Iconize[NotebookFileName[], NotebookFileName], 
   "makefolder" -> Automatic , "fileinfix" -> Automatic, 
   "fileappend" -> Automatic, "echoalerts" -> Automatic, 
   "soundalerts" -> Automatic, "volume" -> .25, "limitalerts" -> 3, 
   OverwriteTarget -> True, Options[CreateDirectory]};

FormatOptions[stage];
```

Below is my attempt at automating the `Iconize` step with a `Replace`-ment `Rule`. There are three strings in the `rules` that should have been `Iconize`-ed. Instead it drops the entire list, only returning one icon from the first long string it encounters. Also, please allow me to stress that the `OptionValues` in this example are not the same as the prior example.

Please help. Thank you.

```
(* almost slightly works *)

ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll[stage, rules];

Options[stage] = {"backuprate" -> 2, "source" -> NotebookFileName[], 
   "makefolder" -> "this-folder-name-is-38-charscters-long", 
   "fileinfix" -> 
    "this-string-that-will-be-infixed-to-a-filename-is-55-charscters-\
long", "fileappend" -> "too-short-to-iconize-33-chracters", 
   "echoalerts" -> Automatic, "soundalerts" -> Automatic, 
   "volume" -> .25, "limitalerts" -> 3, OverwriteTarget -> True, 
   Options[CreateDirectory]};

FormatOptions[stage];
rules = Options[stage]
rules /. 
 KeyValuePattern[x_ -> y_String?(StringLength[#] >= 35 &)] -> 
  x -> Iconize[y, "String"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might start by figuring out the iconization step in isolation. You could try something like this:

```
IconizeLong[length_][Rule[key_, str_]] := 
  If[
    length <= StringLength[ToString@str], 
    key -> Iconize[str, key], 
    key -> str]

IconizeLong[5]["a" -> "abcde"](* should result in a iconized object*)
IconizeLong[5]["a" -> "abcd"](* should result in no change *)
```

Now let's assume you have options for `stage`:

```
IconizeLong[5] /@ Options[stage]
```

will give you a list with long items iconized. For formatting this nicely, it looks like you want a column:

```
Column[IconizeLong[5] /@ Options[stage]]
```

Now you want to add the other elements of the formatted options:

```
FormatOptions2[sym_Symbol, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Row[
    {Style[("Options[" <> (SymbolName[sym]) <> "]"), Bold], 
     Style[" \[Rule] ", Orange], 
     Column[IconizeLong[5] /@ Options[sym]]}]
```

I haven't tested this with anything other than the stage options you provided, but it seems to work in that case at least:

```
FormatOptions2[stage]
```

Obviously you'd choose whatever length threshold you want, maybe even make that an argument to the formatting function. Also, I don't know if you want the key used as the icon label, but you'll need to come up with some way of setting that.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I really appreciate this, and I may end up using it, but I think I could have derived a very similar solution on my own. You see, this kind of problem feels a lot like lt should be a simple one-liner using a `Replace`-ment `Rule`. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay, well then replace KeyValuePattern with HoldPattern.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH :) here it is and its a one-liner: `Options[stage] /. 
 HoldPattern[x_ -> y_String?(StringLength[#] >= 35 &)] -> 
  x -> Iconize[y, String]`

Comment: i just figured out a shorter solution but i prefer your `HoldPattern` suggesting because it looks safer, here is the slightly shorter one: `Options[stage] /. (x_ -> y_String /; StringLength[y] >= 35) -> (x ->Iconize[y, String])`